# Add specific message in csv pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am having two dataframe and I want to add specific message before each dataframe in single csv.
For eg.

```
df1
id val
1   5
2   6
3   7

df2
id val
8   1
4   2
3   8
```

I want output in csv file which I can do it using :

```
with open('1.csv', 'w') as f:
    df1.to_csv(f)
with open('1.csv', 'a') as f:
    df2.to_csv(f, header=True)
```

It will give two csv file one after another but I want to add specific message before each dataframe and output should be like:

```
This is df1

id val
1   5
2   6
3   7

This is df2

id val
8   1
4   2
3   8
```

Any help would be appriciated
Thanks a lot.

Comment: All you need to do is add `print("This is df1.",file=f)` inside your two `with` statements.  Of course, what you will end up with is not a CSV file at all.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add `print("This is df1.",file=f)` inside your two with statements. Of course, what you will end up with is not a CSV file at all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).